# WPF Outside of window

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

In Windows OS, when you run the installer file, OS asks permission to install the software. In that condition, window was focused and outside of window is inaccessible and **blacked**. And I searched to make such kind of window to create in WPF. But I just found inaccessibility opportunity. Is there any solution to customize the outside of the window color?

[image: such like this! I want to make the window sharper than outside of the window]

Comment: Huh?  You mean a UAC elevation prompt?  You can't, and shouldn't, try to prevent a user from using their computer, so nope.  If you're talking about showing a child window while blocking access to the parent, then you want to create a **modal** dialog.

Comment: Yeah i set owner, to the child window. But, do you mean i couldn't set Opacity or Blurring outside of the window(such like this customization)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.  Can you add an image that demonstrates what you want to happen, and what you currently have that isn't working?

Comment: Such like above window, purpose is to make window looks sharp so you can focus on the window? Clear?

Comment: So blur the world, then present your window as sharp.  You can do this, however it would be annoying for the user and hard for you to accomplish.  This is because you would have to overlay the world with your startup window which would have to be chromeless and transparent, then add a blur effect to the window, then open up a modal child window which would be your application.  That's a bit too hard to fit into an answer, and if I were using your application I'd hate you for being annoying.  So I'd advise dropping this.

Comment: So thanks for sharing and caring! And I don't care if you hate my application such like this. I am purposely making just one window to make that important and asking from expert on WPF. Also I'm sure there are more people interesting about Customization of window outside area. By the way thanks again